# Not getting form data sent via ajax post request rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to send my form data which includes some text fields and one image field to controller via ajax post request.

The form data looks like this:

[image]

And this is the ajax call i am making

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      processData: false,
      data: {'new_post_data': data},
      url: "/posts/newpostcreate",
      success: function(resp, status){
       }
  });
```

The request is being sent but in the controller I am getting something like

```
ActionController::Parameters {"object Object"=>nil, "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"new_post_create"} permitted: false>
```

I have spent many hours looking for a solution and trying different solutions but still it does not work. I'm not getting what I am missing.

Comment: Permitted: False means you haven't whitelisted the params in your controller via "strong parameters".  Show us your controller.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Isn't the logging done prior to hitting any parameter massaging? That it's trying to use the string representation of a JS object as a key I'd still suspect the client side first anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong format and that your 'data' variable is empty (hint given in the Params: `"object Object"=>nil`). Try passing this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { new_post_data: "test" },
      url: "/posts/newpostcreate",
      success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
      }
  });
```

Edit: I realized you have a file attachment in your data. I think your safest bet is to create a FormData object and assign all your data to it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

I am not sure about `processData: false`. I never used it.

Comment: @ Alex yes now i am getting <ActionController::Parameters {"new_post_data"=>"test", "controller"=>"api/v1/posts", "action"=>"new_post_create"} permitted: false>.I am not getting why the data variable is being taken as null

Comment: Even if it's empty it shouldn't be using the JS object string representation as the key.

Comment: @ Alex getting Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation on passing the data i have inspected and found that data is not null now.What should i do to avoid this error

Comment: You have missed `processData: false,` that could be the reason to the error.

Comment: @Pavan if i use processData: false then i am not getting the data in controller

Comment: @yogeshmanjhi What is your method name? is it `newpostcreate` or `new_post_create`

Comment: @Pavan method name is new_post_create

Comment: @yogeshmanjhi Then you should change this `url: "/posts/newpostcreate",` to `url: "/posts/new_post_create",`

Comment: @Pavan that does not help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149072/discussion-between-pavan-and-yogeshmanjhi).

Comment: @ Alex thanks finally achieved that by adding FormData object and assigning all data to it

Comment: @ Alex thanks, you are correct its the FormData object that is needed no need of xhr parameter just tried to removed xhr and it worked.Accepting 
 your answer.Thanks a lot for your suggestions.